# Call php webservice from iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I want to know how to call php webservice from iPhone application.Also i have to pass parameters to the webservice.Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). Great library for doing what you're asking for.